# Java with Spigot API, code won't save defaults on my .yml file

Tags: java, bukkit

I'm currently having a problem on saving my default values of a YAML file (which I have defined on my Eclipse). The YAML file does generate, but it is an empty file. (Should be something that I've already typed earlier on the Eclipse). Can somebody figured out what I have missed?

Perhaps there is something wrong in the setup() method on the SettingsManager class, because it is the method that generates the lang.yml file, and the setup() method is called on onEnable() on the Main class.

---

**My full classes on pastebin:**

[http://pastebin.com/wEeiXyRi (Main.class)](http://pastebin.com/wEeiXyRi)

[http://pastebin.com/82Hf8nB7 (SettingsManager.class)](http://pastebin.com/82Hf8nB7)

I also added the files `config.yml` and `lang.yml` in the project folder in my Eclipse.

Comment: Hmm. I can't see you setting any information (via  e.g. .set("X.Y", 123)) that has to be saved inside.

Comment: I'm setting it manually through my Eclipse, and having the "lang.yml" inside my project folder

here's a screenshot of what I meant

http://i.imgur.com/ypIy5AR.png

Answer (score 0):

You need to load the defaults from their config file in your src directory, then using a config stream, set them to your config. For example, with your language config:

`defConfigStream = new InputStreamReader(plugin.getResource("lang.yml"), "UTF8");`

Then, assuming langConfig is your config variable:

```
YamlConfiguration defConfig = YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration(defConfigStream);
langConfig.setDefaults(defConfig);
```

And save your config.

Answer (score 0):

Bukkit provides a helpful method to save the default config.yml file in the form of `JavaPlugin.saveDefaultConfig()` ([javadocs here](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/bukkit/org/bukkit/plugin/java/JavaPlugin.html#saveDefaultConfig())) to your plugin's directory. Note that it won't overwrite an existing config file.

If you want to save other files that are contained within your .jar plugin file to the plugin's directory,, you can use the `JavaPlugin.saveResource()` method ([javadocs here](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/bukkit/org/bukkit/plugin/java/JavaPlugin.html#saveResource(java.lang.String,%20boolean))). For example, in your `onEnable` if you include the line `this.saveResource("lang.yml", true)` the lang.yml in the plugin directory will always be overwritten by the version contained within the jar file.

Answer (score 0):

during enable and disable use

`getConfig().options().copyDefaults(true);
            reloadConfig();
            saveConfig();`

the same thing happened to me, the code updates your config before saving, so it doesn't override your changes